# Redux and promise progress

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

How can I handle and promise progress in redux ?

I want to show some spinning bar or something while the promise is executing, I'm using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to handle the requests, but they have an api to handle the progress that goes like this in the config object of the request:

```
{  
   progress: function(progressEvent) {
       // Do whatever you want with the native progress event
   }
}
```

But I can only send the request in a redux action, like:

```
return {
    type: "HTTP_REQUEST",
    payload: axios.get("/webAPI/data", configObj)
}
```

How can I handle the progress event with those conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking at just showing a spinner as opposed to a progress bar you really don't need the progress function. Rather I would recommend something along these lines:

```
const axiosAction = function(configObj) {
  // We have to thunk the dispatch since this is async - need to use the thunk middleware for this type of construct
  return dispatch => {
    /* action to notify the spinner to start (ie, update your store to have a
    loading property set to true that will presentationally start the spinner) */
    dispatch({
      type: 'AXIOS_REQUEST_STARTING'
    });
    return axios.get("/webAPI/data", configObj)
        .then(res => {
          /* action to set loading to false to stop the spinner, and do something with the res */
          return dispatch({
            type: 'AXIOS_REQUEST_FINISHED',
            payload: res,
          })
        })
        .catch(err => /* some error handling*/);
  };
}
```

Edited to add link for [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 2):

While gabdallah's answer is correct, I feel it only partially answers the question. The code from both answers can easily be combined, if you wish to do so.

If you *do* want to show the progress to the user, you can dispatch specific progress actions from your progress callback, with the current progress as payload. Something like this:

```
{  
   progress: function(progressEvent) {
       return dispatch({
           type: "HTTP_REQUEST_PROGRESS",
           payload: {
               url: "/webAPI/data",
               currentBytes: progressEvent.current,
               totalBytes: progressEvent.total // properties on progressEvent made up by yours truly
           }
       });
   }
}
```

In essence, you just need another action that represent `request progress`, just like you already have an action for initiating a request (and probably one for both a successful and unsuccessful outcome).